# How to restrict client accessing another client messages

Tags: mqtt, activemq-artemis

There are 2 clients (`A` and `B`) that are connected to the ActiveMQ Artemis broker. The protocol we are using is MQTT. Both clients have different topic templates that they subscribe. For example client `A` has subscription topic template of `school/readings/#` and client `B` has subscription  topic template of `Domestic/readings/#`.

There will be our server that subscribes all the topics with their respective template.

If client `B` decides to read all the incoming messages to the broker by subscribing with topic (`#` or `school/#`) then there could be a data leak. The requirement here is only our server should subscribe all the topics and other client should have restrictions in topic subscription.

Is there any way to restrict clients subscription or is there any way to avoid this type of data leak?

Both the clients should have the privilege to publish and subscribe to the broker, but one client should not subscribe to another client's topics.

Comment: The messages are sent to every subscriber. What do you mean with `data leak`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no data leak, unless you configured authorization rules and they are not being enforced or you find a way to get unauthorized access when security is enabled (in that case open a bug [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/ARTEMIS)). Please, find out [here](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/security.html) the documentation on how to use `security-settings` to configure the authorization rules for your use case.